# Gracenote API call to get Programs/Shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am trying to fetch programs by search of query (name of show) through the Gracenote API.

For reference:
http://developer.tmsapi.com/io-docs (v1.1/programs/search)

Using the example (to fetch movies) listed on their website, it works fine.

http://developer.tmsapi.com/Sample_Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tile {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 2px;
                padding: 4px;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 15px;
                width:250px;
                font-family: Avenir;
                color: white;
            }
            </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            // construct the url with parameter values
            var apikey = "xxxxx";
            var baseUrl = "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1";
            var showtimesUrl = baseUrl + '/movies/showings';
            var zipCode = "78701";
            var d = new Date();
            var today = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate();

            $(document).ready(function() {

                              // send off the query
                              $.ajax({
                                     url: showtimesUrl,
                                     data: {    startDate: today,
                                     zip: zipCode,
                                     jsonp: "dataHandler",
                                     api_key: apikey
                                     },
                                     dataType: "jsonp",
                                     });
                              });

                              // callback to handle the results
                              function dataHandler(data) {
                                  $(document.body).append('<h2>Found ' + data.length + ' movies showing within 5 miles of ' + zipCode+'</h2>');
                                  $.each(data, function(index, movie) {
                                         var movieData = '<div class="tile"><img src="http://fanc.tmsimg.com/' + movie.preferredImage.uri + '?api_key='+apikey+'"><br/>';
                                         movieData += 'Title:' + movie.title + '<br>';
                                         movieData += 'ID: ' + movie.tmsId + '<br>';
                                         if (movie.ratings) {movieData += 'Rating: ' + movie.ratings[0].code;}
                                         else {movieData += 'Rating: ' + 'N/A';}
                                         $(document.body).append(movieData);
                                         });
                              }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to modify it (to fetch programs), I fail to retrieve any data, all returned as undefined.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tile {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 2px;
                padding: 4px;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 15px;
                width:250px;
                font-family: Avenir;
                color: white;
            }
            </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            // construct the url with parameter values
            var apikey = "xxxxx";
            var baseUrl = "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1";
            var showtimesUrl = baseUrl + '/programs/search';
            var zipCode = "78701";
            var showName = 'Friends';

            $(document).ready(function() {

                              // send off the query
                              $.ajax({
                                     url: showtimesUrl,
                                     data: {    q: showName,
                                     jsonp: "dataHandler",
                                     api_key: apikey
                                     },
                                     dataType: "jsonp",
                                     });
                              });

                              // callback to handle the results
                              function dataHandler(data) {
                                  $(document.body).append('<h2>Found ' + data.length + ' movies showing within 5 miles of ' + zipCode+'</h2>');
                                  var programs = data.hits;
                                  $.each(data, function(index, program) {
                                         var programData = '<div class="tile">' + program.entityType + '<br/>';
                                         programData += 'Title:' + program.title + '<br>';
                                         programData += 'ID: ' + program.tmsId + '<br>';
                                         $(document.body).append(programData);
                                         });
                              }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Actual result:** (Response Status: 200)

undefined

Title: undefined

ID: undefined

**Expected result:** (Response Status: 200)

Show

Title: Friends

ID: SH001151270000

Comment: As we cannot make a request to test this, could you please edit the question to include an example of the response you receive back from the API

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest you update the version of jQuery you're using. 1.5 is over 8 years out of date

Comment: Thanks Rory, I forgot to update the jQuery from the sample code from their website. Will update my post above. Ps. I sent you an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort it out by looking at the array.

For the Movies sample code provided by the website the array returned a property path as **[""0""].entityType** but for Program it is returned as **hits[""0""].program.entityType**.

So I replaced **data** with **data.hits** and **program.entityType** with **program.program.entityType** etc.

```
  function dataHandler(data) {
    $(document.body).append('<h2>Found ' + data.hits.length + ' shows.</h2>');
    $.each(data.hits, function(index, program) {
      var programData = '<div class="tile">' + program.program.entityType + '<br/>';
      programData += 'Title:' + program.program.title + '<br>';
      programData += 'ID: ' + program.program.tmsId + '<br>';
      $(document.body).append(programData);
    });
  }
```

[image]